# Not able to inject Iterator implementing class in JMockit

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

I have one scenario that I need to test using `TestNg` and `JMockit`. I have these sample classes to illustrate the case.

```
public class Service {

    private Dao dao;

    public String fetch() {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultIterator iterator = dao.fetch();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String string = iterator.next();
            items.add(string);
        }
        return String.join(", ", items);
    }
}
```

In service class I need to inject a `Dao` dependency.

```
    public class Dao {

    public ResultIterator fetch() {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        return new ResultIterator(data);
    }
}
```

The `Dao` class fetches the data from a backend and gives an instance of `ResultIterator` class.

```
public class ResultIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    private int index = 0;
    private List<String> data;

    public ResultIterator(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        String res = data.get(index);
        index++;
        return res;
    }

}
```

To run the test case

```
public class NGTest {

    @Tested(fullyInitialized = true)
    Service service;

    @Injectable
    Dao dao;

    @Test
    public void testFetchedData() throws Exception {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("E", "F", "G", "H"));
        new Expectations() {
            {
                dao.fetch();
                result = new ResultIterator(data);
            }
        };
        String out = service.fetch();
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

When I run the test case I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.Iterator is not mockable`. Here I don't really want to mock the iterator. I just want to pass it as a result in expectations block. I'm using `TestNg 6.8` and `JMockit 1.46`